# Running SQL Script With BCP of Share File via Specific Server

Tags: sql-server, bcp

We have several SHELL scripts on 2 different servers that run SQLcmd.exe. The script opens a SQL file that does a BCP of a txt file on a shares server into the database. The problem is on one server the script won't run. The error that we get is:

> Cannot bulk load because the file "\\zzzz.net\zzzzz\scripts\a.csv" could not be
>   opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).

This server does have access to that file share. We have also tested this script on 3 other servers and it works fine. It just happens to be this server. Is there any reason why one server would not work?

Following is the command line that we call that works on 4 servers but doesn't work on 1:

> "c:/sqlcmd" -U "SA" -d "XXXX" -w 600 -S "XXXXX" -P "XXXXXX" -i
>   \\zzzz.net\zzzzz\scripts\a.sql

Here is the code in a.sql:

> BULK INSERT tblPerformanceLoadMellon FROM
>   '\\zzzz.net\zzzzz\scripts\a.csv' with
>   (DATAFILETYPE='char',FIELDTERMINATOR=',')

Comment: wild guess: the succesful server has the file on local disks?

Comment: No. The file is on a file server. Not on any local disks. It is actually also 3 other servers that can access the file server and run the script no problem. Just this one in specific has an issue.

Comment: more details are needed otherwise only wild guesses are possible. which users are involved? service users are the same on both sql servers? file permission are ok? and so on...

Comment: We pass the SA user ID/password to SQLcmd.exe. It is just one SQL server that we access from both servers. Its the same exact script.